# Java KeyPressed KeyRelease and holding a Key

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keypress

I'm trying to to get my character to move left and right, and then stop when you take your fingers off of the left or right arrow keys but what keeps happening is he keeps going.  Here is my keypressed:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();//getting keycodes
        if (bInGame) {            
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    nReqdx = -1;
                    nReqdy = 0;  
                    }
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    nReqdx = 1;
                    nReqdy = 0;
                    }
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {//Interaction
                    //Yet to be filled
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && tTimer.isRunning()) {
                    bInGame = false;
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE) {
                    if (tTimer.isRunning()) {
                        tTimer.stop();
                    } else {
                        tTimer.start();
                    }
                }
        } else {
            if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
                bInGame = true;
                GameRun();
            }
        }
    }
```

And Here is my KeyReleased:

```
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();         
            if (key == Event.LEFT || key == Event.RIGHT) {
                bMoving = false;
                if (bMoving == false) {
                nReqdx = 0;
                nReqdy = 0;
                nCurrentSpeed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I have discovered is that it never reaches the key release, I think, but I don't know why.  Also don't ask me to post all of my code because I have about 450 lines, just ask me to post where a variable is declared or something like if you need more information to figure out what is going wrong.

I have now been wondering if my character keeps going because he is animated, maybe his set images keep causing him to go.

Here is where he is animated.

```
     public void DoAnimation() {
    nAstroImgCount--;
    if (nAstroImgCount <= 0) {
        nAstroImgCount = nASTROIMGDELAY;
        nAstroAnimPos = nAstroAnimPos + nAstroImgDir;
        if (nAstroAnimPos == (nASTROANIMIMGCOUNT - 1) || nAstroAnimPos == 0) {
            nAstroImgDir = -nAstroImgDir;
        }
    }
}

public void DrawAstronaut(Graphics2D g2d) {
    if (nViewDX == -1) {
        DrawAstronautLeft(g2d);
    } else if (nViewDX == 1) {
        DrawAstronautRight(g2d);
    } else {
        DrawAstronautStand(g2d);
    }
}

public void DrawAstronautLeft(Graphics2D g2d) {
    switch (nAstroAnimPos) {
        case 1:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkLeft1, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 2:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkLeft2, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 3:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkLeft3, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 4:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkLeft4, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 5:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkLeft5, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 6:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkLeft6, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        default://default of him standing still
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroStandLeft, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
    }
}

public void DrawAstronautRight(Graphics2D g2d) {//Same as the left but right
    switch (nAstroAnimPos) {
        case 1:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkRight1, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 2:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkRight2, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 3:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkRight3, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 4:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkRight4, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 5:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkRight5, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        case 6:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroWalkRight6, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroStandRight, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
    }
}
```

What I mean is that he keeps going because his animation never stops.  Wondering if someone could confirm that or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing two different types of the key constants. In one hand you are using `KeyEvent`, on the other hand `Event`.

In the `KeyEvent` class it is:

```
/**
 * Constant for the non-numpad <b>left</b> arrow key.
 * @see #VK_KP_LEFT
 */
public static final int VK_LEFT           = 0x25;   // = 37
```

In the `Event` class it is:

```
/**
 * The Left Arrow key, a non-ASCII action key.
 */
public static final int LEFT                = 1006;
```

Since the `getKeyCode()` method is returning the constant from the `KeyEvent` class, you have to use in **both** cases the `KeyEvent.VK_LEFT` constant.

Comment: +1 for catching the issue and it is preferable to use Key Bindings mechanism instead of `KeyListener`S

Comment: So would I change the Events to KeyEvents and LEFT and RIGHT to VK_, if so I changed that already and it didn't help

Comment: How did you discover, that your program isn't reaching the `keyReleased` method at all? Did you debug it by setting a breakpoint to this method?

Comment: I don't know how professional this is but I just had a system.out.println with some text in it that never printed out when I released the key.

Comment: At the first line? Or in the inner if statement? If the former, you have should look at your `KeyListener`, where you added it. This is a scope you don't have shown us yet.

Comment: It was after the if structures where I tested

Comment: So add another `System.out.println("Key: " + key);` after the line `int key = e.getKeyCode();` to figure out, whats going wrong (in case, you don't like to just debug your code).